# Mysql Shell doesn't change the configuration of my database for group replication

Tags: configuration, mysql-5.7, my.cnf, group-replication

I am attempting to use a preexisting database on multiple nodes in a group replication setting. I am using mysqlsh 8.0.16, mysql server 5.7.24 and ubuntu 16.04 as the host.

When I attempt to configure the database with mysqlsh, I get the following output

```
Some configuration options need to be fixed:
+----------------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Variable                         | Current Value | Required Value | Note                                             |
+----------------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| binlog_checksum                  | CRC32         | NONE           | Update the server variable                       |
| enforce_gtid_consistency         | OFF           | ON             | Update the config file and restart the server    |
| gtid_mode                        | OFF           | ON             | Update the config file and restart the server    |
| log_bin                          | <not set>     | <no value>     | Update the config file                           |
| log_bin                          | OFF           | ON             | Update read-only variable and restart the server |
| log_slave_updates                | OFF           | ON             | Update the config file and restart the server    |
| master_info_repository           | FILE          | TABLE          | Update the config file and restart the server    |
| relay_log_info_repository        | FILE          | TABLE          | Update the config file and restart the server    |
| server_id                        | 0             | <unique ID>    | Update the config file and restart the server    |
| transaction_write_set_extraction | OFF           | XXHASH64       | Update the config file and restart the server    |
+----------------------------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

and i specify the file used (i tried with multiple cnf files that are in the mysql directory).

However the files do not get edited despite having root privileges, none of the changes seem to take effect when I restart the server (or the instance it is running on).

Perhaps there is an elegant way to do this manually instead?

Comment: You have to manually edit the configuration files

Comment: I thought so. Is binlog_checksum also set in the cnf file? I cannot find entries for many of these variables so I assume they are defaults